# Update devise user password using a custom method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise for authentication and trying to change the password of certain users to their date of birth using a method

```
def set_dob_password id
 @user = User.find(id)
 @user.update_attribute(password: @user.birth_date)
end
```

isn't working
. What is the best way of doing this ?

Comment: It is not working because your parameter is only one and you are using `update_attributes` which uses multiple params.

Comment: @araratan updating a single value of multiple values is not real problem here it wont work with update_attribute either

Comment: you can try using devise own method `account_update` like `@user.account_update(:password => @user.birth_date)`

Comment: @HarryBomrah I tried and I am getting `undefined method 'account_update' for<object>` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it won't work! Devise stores encrypted passwords only in the DB. If you look at the users table you won't see a 'password' field but 'encrypted_password' column instead.

You first have to encrypt the password.

```
pw = BCrypt::Password.create(@user.birth_date)
@user.update_attribute(:encrypted_password, pw)
```

Make sure you have the 'bcrypt' gem first.

Answer (score 0):

@user.update_attributes(password: params[:password], password_confirmation: params[:password_confirmation]). You need to update both password + password confirmation. So in your case replace parmas with user DoB.

Comment: @user.update_attributes(password: params[:password], password_confirmation: params[:password_confirmation]). You need to update both password + password confirmation. So in your case replace parmas with user DoB.